# Mongodb calculate area of polygon

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

Hi I have objects like this on my mongodb

```js
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53a9cf13a004869fb0476859"),
  "id" : NumberLong(4090259),
  "version" : "3",
  "changeset" : "10265399",
  "uid" : "136321",
  "user" : "Teddy73",
  "timestamp" : "2012-01-01T21:32:37Z",
  "poly" : {
    "type" : "Polygon",
    "coordinates" : [[
        [8.6030412, 49.6544071], [8.602331, 49.6556077],
        [8.6073617, 49.6575444], [8.6081741, 49.6564124], [8.6030412, 49.6544071]
    ]]
  },
  "natural" : "water",
  "source" : "landsat"
}
```

is it possible to calculate the area of poly?

In Postgres there is a function called

```js
area()
```

Comment: i dont want to write the algorithm by myself

Comment: MongoDB does not presently have any operators such as this. For most purposes, such as if you wish to query by the "area" covered by the polygon, then your best approach is to externally calculate and store the "area" as a different field on your document.

Comment: ok please write your comment as an answer so i can accept it